# Include new template in magento widget

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have installed VES MOTOZZ theme for magento 1.9.2. I am using it's page builder to build pages. But to add new functionality like search form, I've created new phtml file in `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/ves/search/search.phtml`
I want to include that search.phtml in my home page by inserting it as a template in one of the existing magento widget. I tried to insert it by going `CMS -> Widgets -> Search(I've created this widget) -> Widget Options -> Template`

But it's not showing content of my widget. I am completetly new to magento. Any suggestion or help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put below code in your home page. I think your home page will be **CMS >> Pages >> your_home_page**

```
{{block type="core/template" template="ves/search/search.phtml"}}
```